# Concerning the identity in sums of Binomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Consider the following identity
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k+1}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(n-k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k(n-k)=\frac16(n+1)(n-1)n$$
As we can see the partial sums of binomial coefficients are expressed in terms of $3$-rd order polynomial $P_3(n)$, where $n$ is variable of upper bound of summation. We assume that order of resulting polynomial $P_3(n)$ depends on subscript of binomial coefficient being summed up (in our case the order of polynomial is $3=2+1$, where $2$ is subscript of bin. coef.)

**The question:** 
Does there exist a generalized method to represent the sum of binomial coefficients $\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{k}{s}$  in terms of certain polynomials $P_{s+1}(n)=\sum_{k}^{n} F_s(n,k)$ for every non-negative integer $s$? I.e can we always find the function $F_s(n,k)$, such that $\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{k}{s}=\sum_{k}^{n}F_s(n,k)$ ? We assume that order of polynomial is $s+1$ by means of example above.

**The sub-question:** (In case of positive answer to the first question.) Suppose there exists the representation the sums of bin. coef. in terms of polynomials in $n$. How do summation limits of the $\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{k}{s}$ implies to the form of polynomial $P_{s+1} (n)$ exactly?

Comment: This is not a research level question. At any rate, it is straightforward to see that $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{k}{s}=\binom{n+1}{s+1}$. Indeed, choosing $s+1$ numbers out of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ is the same as choosing the largest number first (call this $k+1$), and then choosing the other $s$ numbers from $\{1,2\dots,k\}$. Please ask non-research level questions at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question is revised according to your notice. The sense is following: Can we always find the polynomials $F_s(n,k)$, such that $\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{k}{s}=\sum_{k}^{n}F_s(n,k)$ ?

Comment: Well, the sum is a single polynomial $\binom{n+1}{s+1}$. It is of degree $s+1$ in $n$.

Comment: What does $\sum_k^s$ mean? Anyway, this is moving to math.stackexchange after one more vote, so no need to repost it there yourself :)

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense except that which GH already answered.

Comment: Dont post it to StackExchange, it's already there

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I didnt ask for binomial identity $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k}{s}=\binom{n+1}{s+1}$, I asked how to find such polynomials $F_s(n,k)$ that holds as follows $\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{k}{s}=\sum_{k}^{n}F_s(n,k)$. Just like in example but for every non-negative integer $s$, we have esample for $s=2$. Thank you

Comment: Well, $F_s(n,k)=\binom{k}{s}$ is a trivial solution.

Comment: The question is to find such polynomial $F_s(n,k)$ that $\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{k}{s}=\sum_{k}^{n}F_s(n,k)$. From our example it follows that: $F_2(n,k)=k(n-k)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}F_2(n,k)$. Can you provide examples for $s>2$?

Comment: All you noticed is that $\binom k2-k(n-k)$ sums to 0. There are infinitely many polynomials in $k$ and $n$ which sum to 0.  Adding any one of them to $\binom ks$ gives an example.

Comment: Here is the almost solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091598
Thank to everybody